# Choosing a column which has a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an numpy array as the following

```
all = [[0 0 0],[0 0 1],[0 0 2], ... , [0 0 12]]
```

I am trying to only show the array which has third value 12. In this case [0 0 12]. When I execute my code I get the following output

```
[[0 0 0],[0 0 0],[0 0 12]]
```

I do not know why I get those 0 arrays. My code is below.

````
for i in all:
  if i[2]==12:
    print(all[i]) ```
````

Comment: Don't name a variable `all` because it shadows the built-in `all()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean mask:

When you print your array, you get:

```
print(arr)
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0, 12]])
```

The third row is:

```
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [12]])
```

Now, you can create a boolean mask as:

```
arr[:,2]==12
```

which evaluates to

```
array([False, False, False,  True])
```

this means rows 1-3 don't have 12 as a third element but 4th does.

So you use this mask on `arr`:

```
arr[arr[:,2]==12]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  0, 12]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the value of your arrays that correspond to your condition.

```sh
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 2],
                [0, 0, 10],
                [0, 0, 11],
                [0, 0, 12]])

print(arr[arr[:,2]==12])
```

##### Output

```sh
[[ 0  0 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I am sure that there is a most efficient way to do it rather than a for loop, take a look to the docs of numpy or here in stackoverflow):

```py
import numpy as np
# turn list of lists into a numpy array
all = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,12]])

# use enumerate if you want so you can have the index
for i,ar in enumerate(all.tolist()):
  # look for your value
  if ar[2]==12:
      # as you want the rows just do all[i]
      # if you want the column also all[i][3]
      print( all[i] )
```